# Applying Netplan Access Point settings?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter, netplan

I am upgrading a previous configuration of an AIO server/access point to Ubuntu 20.04. I wrote a Netplan configuration for our interfaces, as follows -

```
network: 
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      addresses:
       - ***.***.***/24
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      addresses:
       - ***.***.***.***/24
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      addresses:
       - 192.168.10.0/24
      gateway4: 192.168.10.2
      access-points:
        "GCSHOTSPOT":
          password: "***********"
          mode: ap
```

This configuration saves, and applies successfully, but no access point is ever generated, even allowing the AP to generate its own gateway & addresses. what am i missing here? I'm running Ubuntu 20.04LTS Focal.
Thanks :D
Jake

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: `dhcp4: no`

Mine works as follows:

```
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.10.1/24]
      access-points:
        "my-wifi":
           password: "securepass"
           mode: ap
```